# Running h2o in Jupyter scala notebook

Tags: scala, jupyter, h2o

I'm trying to get h2o running on a Jupyter notebook with scala kernel, with no success so far. Maybe someone can give me a hint on what could be wrong? The code I'm executing at the moment is

```
classpath.add("ai.h2o" % "sparkling-water-core_2.10" % "1.6.5")

import org.apache.spark.h2o._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("appName").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val h2oContext = new H2OContext(sc).start()
```

It fails on the last line with error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: water/H2O
....
```

And prints out exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot launch H2O on executors: numOfExecutors=1, executorStatus=(driver,false) (Cannot launch H2O on executors: numOfExecutors=1, executorStatus=(driver,false))
org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContextUtils$.startH2O(H2OContextUtils.scala:169)
org.apache.spark.h2o.H2OContext.start(H2OContext.scala:214)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Toree,

In /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/apache_toree_scala/kernel.json

You should add --packages ai.h2o:sparkling-water-core_2.10:1.6.6 on __TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__ , something like

"__TOREE_SPARK_OPTS__": "--master local[*] --executor-memory 12g --driver-memory 12g --packages ai.h2o:sparkling-water-core_2.10:1.6.6",

Then, sc is created when you create your notebook. so you don't need to recreate sc.

Comment: Works like a charm! Enough to do `import org.apache.spark.h2o._` and `val h2oContext = new H2OContext(sc).start()` in the start of the notebook.